# java: command not found after installation

Tags: linux, java, centos, jre

I have installed Jre in my CentOS by following instruction here

[Installation](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#enable)

But the problem is each directory or file contains the "*" (asterisk) at the end of 
file name or directory even though i have fired following command

> chmod a+x or chmod +x

so please tell me how can i execute the executable file because when i am trying to run 
"java" its showing me following error

> java:command not found

here is the screen shot

[image: Image One]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk indicates the specific file is executable, and is only displayed when using a specific argument to `ls` (`-F`). Your `ls` command is likely aliased to include that switch by default. Try navigating to the directory containing java and run `./java`, or add that directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: How to set a path ?

Comment: @Hunt - http://superuser.com/questions/251038/add-folder-to-path