# How to permanently add current directory to PATH in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add folder to PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/251038/add-folder-to-path)

I want to a add a directory to my bash to search in, and I am using the $PATH=.... it works however when I open a new command window it is not there.

How can I permanently add this to the path on Linux?

Comment: [Related topic](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Comment: A remark: adding the current working directory to your path is considered very dangerous. You cannot move around safely in any filesystem anymore. Just imagine, someone places a script called "ls" in his home or any directory which calls "rm -f" on your home or any other sensitive files.

Answer (score 17):

Add a `PATH=$PATH:.` line to your `~/.bashrc`. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/49289/44761) for details.

Comment: Bear in my that adding current folder to the path is security risk, it exposes user of never knowing if its running command from some unsecured folder or a normal system command ( 'ls' for example)

Comment: And before someone claims that adding the current directory at the _end_ of `PATH` is safe, an attacker can still run code as you by creating a program or script named after misspelled commands, such as `mroe`, `tial`, `vmi`, `emasc`, etc.  Those won't be found earlier in the path, and then you end up running the attacker's code as you.

Comment: should you mount a filesystem peppered with malicious executable files or share a box with a bunch of clowns, then prepend your path and cd to such a silly directory, suggest you ```aws ec2 terminate-instances``` or ```docker rmi``` with prejudice