# Sublime Text Editor command not found

Tags: macos, bash, sublime-text-2

I have installed Sublime on my Mac Lion Laptop, and followed the guide here
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html
but as always it did not work. I dont have a ~/bin directory on my Mac.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You could create the symlink in `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a `~/bin` directory, you can create one with `mdkir ~/bin`. This should allow you to follow the guide.

If you do this and Sublime is still not working for you after you've set everything up, then this new folder is probably not included in your `$PATH` (a list of folders that command-line shells search for executables). You can check if this is the case by running `echo $PATH` and see if it contains `/Users/<your username>/bin`. If you don't see the new folder we created in your `$PATH`, then you'll have to add it: [Add folder to PATH](https://superuser.com/q/251038/19841)

A more appropriate location to link the `subl` exceutable might be `/usr/local/bin` if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `bin` directory in your home folder using the Finder or by typing `mkdir ~/bin` in the terminal.
2. Create a symlink to the `subl` app in that `bin` folder by typing `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl` in the terminal.
3. Open or create a file called `.bash_profile` (note the dot!) in your home directory using Sublime Text. (Your home directory will be the one in the Finder with the home icon. You can get the Finder to show the home directory quickly by typing `open ~` in the terminal.)
4. Add the `~/bin` directory to your `$PATH` by editing the `.bash_profile` file you've just created and adding the line `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`. Then save the file.
5. Reload your .bash_profile so that the updated $PATH is picked up by typing `source ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal.

You should now be able to use the `subl` command at the terminal prompt. It's also worth noting that you can put the `bin` folder anywhere you like if you don't want to put it in your home folder.