# Sublime Text 2 "subl" command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, sublime-text-2

I have followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/471158/sublime-text-editor-command-not-found) super user post to get sublime command line **subl command** to work in terminal to no avail.

I have the following bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

and my $PATH outputs

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I also created a sym-link with the following code

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

However **subl** command returns command not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$PATH` doesn't contain `~/bin`, which is why it doesn't work. Are you sure the second statement is executed properly?

You can safely create the symlink somewhere else though, e.g. in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```