# Program built from source is unrecognized by the terminal but if i do it with sudo

Tags: debian, terminal, sudo

i've built a program from source in /usr/local/sbin but now if in a terminal i write "program-name" the terminal say that the command was not found. The program is seen by the terminal only if i do "sudo program-name" or if i go manually in the /usr/local/sbin directory and write ./program-name. I want to be able to run the program as normal user not sudo,without manually go in the sbin directory. How can i do this?

p.s.: I use Debian.

Comment: You could add `/usr/local/sbin` to your `PATH` (see [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/251038/add-folder-to-path))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `sudo`, you normally get `root`'s `PATH`.  Your shell uses `PATH` to find programs. You can adjust your own `PATH` (adding `/usr/local/sbin`).  See for example *[Add folder to PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/251038/add-folder-to-path)*.